# Google Desktop Search result - missing icon

Tags: google-desktop-search

While using google desktop search(GDS) search shortcut (ie. Google desktop @ start menu), sometimes the icon is missing. Is there any way to let GDS re-index it or get the icon back? Thanks.

Comment: What Windows version? And if possible add a screenshot!

Comment: OS: WinXP SP3

please see below sreenshot. Some search results giving circles windows default icon while they have their own shortcut icon (and looking good in the start menu).
http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/3354/gdsicon.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the Social Technet forums:](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprogeneral/thread/8bd1b91e-9d88-4ef3-889b-5aba1a05320e)

> Do these shortcurs work right now?
>
> As the icons show as System default
>   icons, please right click
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start
>   Menu\Programs folder, and choose
>   properties, change to the Previous
>   Versions tab, now you can double click
>   the previous versions to check in
>   which version the shortcuts are fine.
>   Then you can choose the version, you
>   can click Restore button to restore.
>
> If there is not a previous version is
>   good, since you have many shortcuts,
>   it would take long time to change the
>   icon associations to the correct one.
>   You can create a new account, then
>   check if the shortcuts in the new
>   account works fine, then you can copy
>   the C:\Users\new account
>   name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start
>   Menu\Programs to replace the
>   C:\Users\old
>   account\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start
>   Menu\Programs folder in your older
>   user.
>
> After that, if you want to customize
>   the shortcuts, it's better to copy and
>   paste the shortcuts to the folder
>   which you want.

Basically the easiest way to restore it is creating a dummy account and copy+paste the default shortcuts from there (given that the application was installed for "all" users).